# How does CPU access BIOS instructions stored in external memory?

Tags: bios, firmware, computer-architecture

During the process of booting, CPU reads address of system BIOS from the Reset Vector and jumps to the location where BIOS is stored. My question here is:

- As BIOS is stored on some external memory like EEPROM (and not in main memory), how does CPU access this external memory?
- Is this external memory already mapped to some region of main memory? and does the CPU just jump to this mapped region to access BIOS instructions? Or it actually accesses the instructions from external memory where BIOS is stored?

Comment: *"As BIOS is stored on some external memory like EEPROM (and not in main memory)"* -- FYI the main memory is also "external" memory.  The typical PC has RAM chips soldered on *removable* modules.  Or do you have a special definition for "external"?

Answer (score 1):

BIOS is only another memory location as RAM.

CPUs are programmed to read an specific address location (the "reset vector") when they start, so in that location is where the BIOS EEPROM is located. It used to be  000FFFF0h.